# Ubuntu 12.04 Terminal and dual display issue

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, command-line

After upgrading to 12.04 I had a lot of issues with the dual desktop environment. The unity bar is appended to both sides, so when I'm dragging windows from one monitor to the other it hangs on the hidden unity bar and then finally lets me force it over.  While trying to switch to cinnamon which seemed to have aborted on confirming install, my terminal will come up but is now blank with no cursor..

Usually I have a good time troubleshooting and fixing things in Ubuntu, but not so much this round. I don't expect much assistance with the dual monitor situation, but anyone have any idea how I can get my terminal back to normal.. I'm sure once I reboot it will be fine.. BTW, I've messed with Compbiz, MyUnity, and ATI